# What's the difference between UI thread and Render thread?

Tags: windows-phone-7

And, if i call

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                //Do work 
            });
```

or

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                //Do work 
            });
```

**which thread will work?**

and

**Does Deployment.Current.Dispatcher the same as this.Dispatcher?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the difference between UI thread and Render thread?

UI thread calculates on CPU

Render thread on GPU

> which thread will work?

UI

> Does Deployment.Current.Dispatcher the same as this.Dispatcher?

Yes